# How to permanently delete a file stored in GIT?

Tags: git

I backed up my database to GIT just so I could get the db at my home computer.

I don't want this file to be versioned, it was just a 1 time thing really.

Can I delete it for good so GIT doesn't keep track of it going forward or historically?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

I always find [Guides: Completely remove a file from all revisions feed](http://github.com/guides/completely-remove-a-file-from-all-revisions) helpful.

> To remove the file called `Rakefile`:
>
> ```
> git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
>   'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Rakefile' \
>   --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
> ```
>
> This command will run the entire history of every branch and tag, changing any commit
>   that involved the file `Rakefile`, and any commits afterwards. Commits
>   that are empty afterwards (because they only changed the Rakefile) are
>   removed entirely.

Comment: thanks, that really works! You can also add: git push --all --force

Comment: Thanks. It took me a few tries because I did not provide the full relative path to the file (from the root), and just had the filename.

Comment: Remember to always warn all your peers when you're about to do a history rewrite on a remote repository (`git push --all --force`), or else they will face all kinds of problems when performing a pull.

Comment: If this happens to you, you must perform a reset on your affected branches. First `git fetch` then `git status`. If you see that the branches have diverged, stash your changes and `git reset --hard origin/<branch>`.

Comment: This didn't work, and corrupted git. All future commits now fail.

Comment: Adam: This does not *corrupt* Git. Commits will not fail. The first push has to be forced. Did you read the linked article?

Comment: life Saver. you really should add git push --all --force.

Comment: Be warned, this reverted a bunch of my files and even moved files back to an old directory. Fortunately, I hadn't made that many changes. In the end, I ended up just deleting the entire repo since I hadn't done that much to it. Git really needs to make it easier to just go into the site and remove a single historical version.

Answer (score 50):

Update for [remote repository](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/4027/how-to-delete-files-permanently-from-your-local-and-remote-git-repositories):

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch FOLDERNAME" -- --all
```

replace FOLDERNAME with the file or folder you wish to remove from the given git repository.

```
rm -rf .git/refs/original/

git reflog expire --expire=now --all

git gc --prune=now

git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

Now push all the changes to the remote repository

```
git push --all --force
```

This would clean up the remote repository.

Comment: This answer was super helpful and worked like a charm for me. I needed to remove a large folder which had accidentally been committed a few months ago, bloating our repo by hundreds of megs. The process took about an hour to complete.I did have an issue with the "git push --all --force". Since these changes were committed to our develop branch, I first had to do a "git checkout develop", then perform the "git push" to get the changes to sync up to the remote repo.

Comment: I try out this procedure and see, that the files are not removed in the remote repository. But they will not checked out when cloning from remote repository. Executing the 4 commands (`rm -rf ...` ... `git gc --aggressive --prune=now`) in the remote repository remove the files in remote repository too. But you need write-access to the remote repository folder.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use bfg for ease.

> The BFG is a simpler, faster alternative to git-filter-branch for cleansing bad data out of your Git repository history:

Removing Crazy Big Files
Removing Passwords, Credentials & other Private data

```
$ bfg --delete-files YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA
```

Or just replace all the occurrences of some file:

```
$ bfg --replace-text passwords.txt
```

check https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/ and https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/

Answer (score 2):

You can with [git filter-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)'s `--index-filter`.

Comment: Link is broken (cannot be found). I believe this is the [same](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share most simplest and easy to understand solution which worked for me.

First clone a fresh copy of your repo, using the --mirror flag:

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/username/youproject.git
```

Then Download latest version of BFG jar file from https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/ rename it as bfg.jar and paste it inside YourRepoName.git folder.

Then run following lines in git bash.

`java -jar bfg.jar --delete-files yourfilename` (only file name is needed, no need to mention path)

`git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive` (it will strip out the unwanted dirty data which has been expelled out due to above command)

I faced issue here. My project was having open pull requests. If there are any open pull requests then you need to run this command

```
git show-ref | cut -d' ' -f2 | grep 'pull-request' | xargs -r -L1 git update-ref -d
```

After this you can simply push master branch.

```
git push -u origin master
```

Its done. But remember to keep a copy in local of old repository before performing above action. All unmerged branches and open pull requests may get deleted.

I reduced my repo size from 40mb to 4mb by removing unwanted apk files which got pushed with my commits.