# Delete all files from previous commits with git filter-branch

Tags: git, github

In my project in github I made big mistake , i forgot to add .gitignore in start , and more files were added to my repo. Now I've added .gitignore where are a lot of files and directories.  I've done a lot of commits before this and  Now I want to delete all unnecessary files from repo  with command `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f passwords.txt' HEAD`. This command deletes password.txt from all previous commits , but I have two questions: 1) what if I want to delete all files that are in .gitignore? What I must to write after `rm`?? 2) After input this command  , git wrote me: "*master branch and 'origin/master' have diverged. Use git pull....*". I didn't use this command , I just use `git push -u`. Explain please what happened with my brancch? Why it is diverged? **P.s. I work alone with my project and have only one branch - master**

Comment: I've had some luck with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6795435/10023098

Answer (score 0):

1. If your .gitignore lists only files (not directories or patterns) the command should be

   ```
   rm -f `cat .gitignore`
   ```

   I recommend to copy your .gitignore to a file out of Git tree to avoid Git changing the file while it filters commits. So:

   ```
   cp .gitignore ../gitignore
   git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f `cat ../gitignore`'
   rm ../gitignore
   ```
2. As for the second question — `git filter-branch` (like any other commit-editing command — amend, rebase, etc.) creates new commits, an entire new branch really, so you you cannot just push filtered branch. You have to force-push it, either with `git push -f origin master` or `git push origin +master`.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I use Visual Studio .Net project and I must to delete also directory ,  because there are some folders in project

Comment: rm -rf `cat ../gitignore`. '-r' means 'recursive'.

Comment: thanks again , but something wrong.. your command is works but I try to delete all files and directories from previous commits and after your command I get next http://i.imgur.com/wGtYm6g.png. Also I've done a copy of .gitignore  with cp command

Comment: Nothing was changed because ../gitignore was not found. Don't know why, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you should use git filter branch,
imagine you want delete all target/ dirs in your previous commits, you can run just 4 commands for that works:

```
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f */target' HEAD

$ rm -rf */target (you use this one to delete target/ dirs on current HEAD)

$ git commit -am 'delete all target/ dirs' --allow-empty

$ git push
```