# Why can't I compress my git repository?

Tags: git, msysgit

I'm using msysGit on windows7 in a 32bit environment. I'm really new to git so I don't know what else I would need to explain here to help.  One thing I can tell you is this repo is a git clone from my svn repo

[image]

Comment: You could try these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826639/repack-of-git-repository-fails.

Comment: Do you have any huge files in the repository?

Comment: Yes, not by choice.  There are some video files. the whole repo is 2.2GB.  The largest file is about 800M in one very old revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are experiencing the same issue as: [Repack of Git repository fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826639/repack-of-git-repository-fails)

They suggest running:

```
git config pack.windowMemory 10m
git config pack.packSizeLimit 20m
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of Git are you using?
Looks like you may have uncovered an issue prevalent in msysgit for repositories > 2 GB.

Found this in the msysgit issue tracker.. http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=194

Also, found some helpful information in.. [Managing large binary files with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540535/managing-large-binary-files-with-git/541490#541490)

Suggestions were to try using [`git-submodule`](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html) for larger binary files. I recommend using this strategy if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your video is almost certainly (lossy) compressed - then there is no way in saving more than say 5%. You should delete it from your repo and use an smb/ftp/whatever share instead. see: [How to permanently delete a file stored in GIT?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2004024/303290)

(for text like files: git compresses old files itself when necessary)