# Git: How to delete committed file permanently?

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I have committed a file that shouldn't be in a git repository.
I have deleted it and committed the deletion, but I can still access the file via the git history.

**How do I delete a committed file permanently, so that there is no trace of it?**

Comment: Does "for always" mean "permanently"?

Comment: And what do you mean with `no trace`? I don't think it is possible to remove the file from the history, it will be present in previous commits. But that is how version control works

Comment: check out Github's [remove sensitive data](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) page

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to permanently delete a file stored in GIT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004024/how-to-permanently-delete-a-file-stored-in-git)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2158271/1615903

Comment: @mardavi That was fgb edit. All and cexbrayat Thank so much for answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Completely remove unwanted file from Git repository history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-unwanted-file-from-git-repository-history)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can remove permanently a file using `filter-branch`. It will apply the command in argument in every revision of your repository.

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf your_file' HEAD
```

[This detailed post](http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/2-permanently-remove-files-and-folders-from-a-git-repository) might help you. The [git doc](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) is pretty helpful too.

As mentioned in the comments, you will also need a `git gc` to clean your local commits and then `git push`to update your remote repository.

Comment: Also missing a `git gc` - until dangling commits are garbage collected they still exist.

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data

The following command will do this:

```
git clone https://github.com/defunkt/github-gem.git
# Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/tekkub/tmp/github-gem/.git/
# remote: Counting objects: 1301, done.
# remote: Compressing objects: 100% (769/769), done.
# remote: Total 1301 (delta 724), reused 910 (delta 522)
# Receiving objects: 100% (1301/1301), 164.39 KiB, done.
# Resolving deltas: 100% (724/724), done.

cd github-gem

git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
  'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Rakefile' \
  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
# Rewrite 48dc599c80e20527ed902928085e7861e6b3cbe6 (266/266)
# Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
```

> This command will run the entire history of every branch and tag, changing any commit that involved the file Rakefile, and any commits afterwards. Commits that are empty afterwards (because they only changed the Rakefile) are removed entirely. Note that you'll need to specify the full path of the file you want to remove, not just its filename.

Comment: You are missing a `git gc` - and there's no mention that this won't affect the remote repo (if there is one).

Comment: @AD7six Follow the given link in my post, there is then the `git gc` command. The posted code is only a short introduction, it is highly recommended to read the whole article.

Comment: your _answer_ is incomplete. It's highly recommended to write answers such that references are supporting - not fundamental - information. I'm quite familiar with the reference though :).