# How to remove all references to a deleted folder in github

Tags: git, github

I had a local directory structure on my machine thus:

`c:\myprojects\project1\`

and

`c:\myprojects\project2\`

Both directories had multiple files within themselves respectively.

On github, I created a repository named `myprojects` under root with username, say, `Tryer`. So, if I navigate to `https://github.com/Tryer?tab=repositories`, I am able to see just 1 repository of mine named `myprojects`. So far, so good.

Then, I issued the following commands to replicate the local directory structure on github.

```
Navigate to c:\myprojects\ on my local machine. Open command prompt.
git init
git add c:\myprojects\project1
git commit -m "firstcommit"
git branch -M master
git remote add origin https://github.com/Tryer/myprojects.git
git push -u origin master
```

This then replicated the `c:\myprojects\project1\` folder online. Then, for `c:\myprojects\project2\`, I did:

```
git add c:\myprojects\project2
git commit -m "project2commit"
git branch -M master
git push -u origin master
```

Now, I wanted to completely remove any online references to `c:\myprojects\project2` since there was a bug in the code. I wanted to maintain the local directory where I would continue work on `project2` and upload it to github only after fixing the bug. `project1` is fine and should remain online.

To do this, I issued:

```
git rm -r --cached c:\myprojects\project2
git commit -m "Removed buggy project2"
git push origin master
```

Now, while this did "remove" `project2` in that when I navigate to `https://github.com/Tryer/myprojects`, I only see `project1` listed, nevertheless, next to `project1`, there is a link to a page with text `Removed buggy project2` (the most recent descriptive name of the commit) which tells me what this commit was about. Here, it provides in full detail what exactly changed in `project2` with a link to a diff between the at-present nonexistent files under `project2` and what they were in the previous buggy commit.

So, `project2` still continues to be "available" online, occupying space, etc.

Is there a way that even this data is removed from online github?

Comment: Check these topics - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/how-do-you-fix-a-bad-merge-and-replay-your-good-commits-onto-a-fixed-merge, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004024/how-to-permanently-delete-a-file-stored-in-git. Overall, if `project2` does not contain some sensitive/secret information, just don't care about that. Usually, when file is removed from git anyway git keeps it in the history - because what if you'd like to go back in time with commits?

Comment: @kosist All your links seem to suggest something extremely complicated. While you suggest not to care, somehow I don't like useless and buggy code lying online in one form or another. I personally feel something this straightforward should be doable. But perhaps there are other reasons why this is not featured except via complicated operations.

Comment: Task of git - is to keep and maintain history of files. So if you modify/remove files from git repository, it will keep their previous states in the history. Because otherwise there would not be a chance to go back to some specific past commit.

Comment: If you want to remove commits, you can use the dangerous `git reset` command. Have you explored that option?